# Need Help about multiple pivot

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I need to get a `pivot` data from this following data :

```
AssetNo  EffectiveDate     Schedule         Interval
AIRT01      2017-11-23      2017-11-23  
AIRT01      2017-11-23      2017-12-23  
AIRT01      2017-11-23      2018-01-23  
AIRT01      2017-11-23      2018-02-23          3M
AIRT01      2017-11-23      2018-03-23  
AIRT01      2017-11-23      2018-04-23  
AIRT01      2017-11-23      2018-05-23          3M, 6M
AIRT01      2017-11-23      2018-06-23  
AIRT01      2017-11-23      2018-07-23  
AIRT01      2017-11-23      2018-08-23          3M
AIRT01      2017-11-23      2018-09-23  
AIRT01      2017-11-23      2018-10-23  
AIRT01      2017-11-23      2018-11-23          3M, 6M, 1Y
```

Need output like this :

```
    AssetNo EffectiveDate Nov-2017 Dec-2017 Jan-2018 Feb-2018 ... May-2018 ... Nov-2018
    AIRT01    2017-11-23                                3M         3M, 6M     3M, 6M, 1Y
```

Is possible to get multiple `pivot` (for a schedule and interval) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this answer:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @cols = STUFF(
                 (
                     SELECT DISTINCT 
                            ','+QUOTENAME(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, c.Schedule,113),8))
                            --','+QUOTENAME(c.Schedule)
                     FROM MyTab c FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                 ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');
SET @query = 'SELECT [AssetNo],EffectiveDate, '+@cols+'from (SELECT 
           [AssetNo],
           EffectiveDate,
           [Interval] AS [amount],
           RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, Schedule,113),8) AS [category]
    FROM MyTab
    )x pivot (max(amount) for category in ('+@cols+')) p';
EXECUTE (@query);
```

Hope this helps you.

**OutPut**:

```
AssetNo EffectiveDate Nov 2017 Dec 2017 Jan 2018 Feb 2018 ... May 2018 ... Nov 2018
AIRT01    2017-11-23                                3M         3M, 6M     3M, 6M, 1Y
```

Comment: is possible to set order in @cols ? because the output like alphabetical start from apr until sept ?